# GOOGLE FORM - How to specify the subfolder name in code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How can I manipulate this line of code so that I can make a new folder based on the response in the google form. I have a field called "Name". I want it so that it not only goes into a Parent folder, but that it creates a new folder with the "Name" of the customer.

How can I do that with the following code?

Google script:

[`Google script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBFst.png)

```
const initialize = () => {
const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
};

const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
try {
// Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
const files = response
  .getItemResponses()
  // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
  .filter(
    (itemResponse) =>
      itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD"
  )
  .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
  // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
  .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

if (files.length > 0) {
  // Each form response has a unique Id
  const subfolderName = response.getId();
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
  files.forEach((fileId) => {
    // Move each file into the custom folder
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
  });
}
} catch (f) {
Logger.log(f);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the function that you create your trigger with to something like this:

```
function initialize() {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t=>t.getHandlerFunction());
  if(!~ts.indexOf('onFormSubmit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}
```

So that you don't create multiple triggers.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    var subfolderName;
    const files = e.response.getItemResponses().filter(itemResponse => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD").map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse()).reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
    e.response.getItemResponses().forEach(r => { if (r.getItem().getTitle() == 'Hold') { subfolderName = r.getResponse(); } });
    if (files.length > 0) {
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

I think that will work but I must admit that I do most of my form coding in the spreadsheet.